# CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) with optional parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a method with optional parameters

```
 void method1(String text,
      {String? text2}) {
    
    method2(text, text2: text2!);
  }
```

Method1 calls another method with optional parameters

```
 void method2(String text,
      {String? text2 = 'helloWorld'}) {
    
    print(text);
    print(text2!);
  }
```

when I pass a null value into text2 when I call method1, I have an error CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) when method1 try to call method2

Should I add a condition in method1 like :

```
 void method1(String text,
      {String? text2}) {
    if(text2 == null)
    {
       method2(text);
    }
    else
    {
       method2(text, text2: text2!);
    }

  }
```

or something easier.

Context: flutter 2.10.4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use ternary operation like:

```
void method1(String text, {String? text2}) {
   text2 != null ? method2(text, text2: text2) : method2(text);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. And if I have 3 optional parameters, you advice to imbricate condition ?

Comment: It depends of what you prefer, but when there is more than 3 conditions I prefer using `if-else` so it's more readable.